# Gaussian channel to get rid of correlations in a Gaussian state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics

Suppose we have a two-mode bosonic Gaussian state, with zero first moments and a $4 \times 4$ covariance matrix $\sigma$:

$$\sigma = \begin{pmatrix} \sigma_A & \sigma_{AB} \\ \sigma_{AB}^T & \sigma_B \end{pmatrix}$$
where $\sigma_A, \sigma_B$ and $\sigma_{AB}$ are $2 \times 2$ matrices.

Is it possible to construct a Gaussian Channel, which gets rid of the correlation terms (i.e. terms in the diagonal block)?

$$\begin{pmatrix} \sigma_A & \sigma_{AB} \\ \sigma_{AB}^T & \sigma_B \end{pmatrix}  \longrightarrow \begin{pmatrix} \sigma_A & 0 \\ 0 & \sigma_B \end{pmatrix} $$

Is there a procedure which involves only Gaussian states and operations, which can achieve the above transformation?